# Replacing a part of a matrix with another one using python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm working on a project (tetris) where I need to  replace a part of a matrix with another matrix. I'm looking for a function that I can use for that. For instance:

```
a = numpy.matrix([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])
b = numpy.matrix([[1,1],[1,1]])

#for the result i want to get

c = [[1,1,0]
     [1,1,0]
     [0,0,0]]
```

Comment: Simply slice and assign : `a[:b.shape[0],:b.shape[1]] =  b`.